# Clarification required regarding max topics supported in Firebase Cloud Messaging per Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The below page from firebase mentions that an App instance can not be part of more than 2K FCM topics.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

> One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.

I have seen related questions and answers. But I still have some doubts.

Let's say, my Flutter-based App XYZ has 50K users. And in a hypothetical scenario, each user has subscribed to one unique topic i.e. 50K topics across users.

Will I be still able to use Firebase FCM for all the 50K topics?

Please help with the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is not on the number of topics that can exists, but the number of topics that a single app instance can subscribe to. A single app *instance* can subscribe to at most 2,000 topics, but there's no such limit across app instances.

So if each of your 50K users has a single app instance, they could subscribe to 50,000 * 20,000 topics.

Comment: What constitutes an 'app instance'? Say I have an app called MY_APP, and I have 50,000 users who have all installed MY_APP. Is MY_APP an app instance or is each individual app installed on a users device an app instance?

Comment: Correct. Each install of your app on a separate device is a unique app instance. It's like in OO programming: `MY-APP` is the class, and each installation of the app on a device is a separate instance of that.

Comment: Interesting. We are getting a 'messaging/message-rate-exceeded' - 'Topic Quota Exceeded' error, but each app instance can only subscribe to a maximum of 6 topics. If an app instance subscribes to the same topic, for example 'updates', multiple times, does that add to the quota?

Comment: That error seems about the message rate, not the number of topic subscriptions per app instance. It's probably best to post a new question about it, with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).