# How many create FCM topics in a server

Tags: django, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

My team was in trouble in push alarm with FCM token in flutter (especially ios),
So we decided to push alarm to each user with topics.

I know that "One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics." in
[Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

But i confused about "One app instance".
Is that mean each android or ios application user can subscribe 2000 topics?
or Each FCM Server can create up to 2000 topics?

I wonder about One app instance's meaning in "One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App instance refers to the unique installs. The 2000-topic-limit is applicable to per app install. More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70521166/20447561).